# SQLlite error code1 table scores has no column named p2name

Tags: android, sql

**this is my code**

i dont understand why im getting this error 
maybe the syntax of creating the table ?

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "scoresDB.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "scores";
public static final String COLUMN_P1_NAME= "p1name";
public static final String COLUMN_P2_NAME= "p2name";
public static final String COLUMN_P1_SCORE= "p1score";
public static final String COLUMN_P2_SCORE= "p2score";

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_DATES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + COLUMN_P1_NAME + " TEXT," + COLUMN_P2_NAME + " TEXT," + COLUMN_P1_SCORE +" TEXT,"  + COLUMN_P2_SCORE +" TEXT"+ ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_DATES_TABLE);
}
```

Comment: Has no column named.... named what?

Comment: i have edited my quastion i cant post the error and i dont know why

Comment: Maybe you need to close the db connection with `db.Close();` after creating the table. Your query doesn't seem wrong..

Comment: Are you sure the error is in your posted code? Post the full logcat

Answer (score 1):

Aah, you need a `;` in the end of the query when you are creating it, like this:

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "scoresDB.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "scores";
public static final String COLUMN_P1_NAME= "p1name";
public static final String COLUMN_P2_NAME= "p2name";
public static final String COLUMN_P1_SCORE= "p1score";
public static final String COLUMN_P2_SCORE= "p2score";

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_DATES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + COLUMN_P1_NAME + " TEXT," + COLUMN_P2_NAME + " TEXT," + COLUMN_P1_SCORE +" TEXT,"  + COLUMN_P2_SCORE +" TEXT"+ ");";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_DATES_TABLE);
}
```